# Standard way for Rails to parse array query params without using brackets in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, query-string

I want a resource URI to look like this:

```
https://domain.tld/resource?param=foo&param=bar&param=baz
```

But Rails requires array query params to use the square bracket notation.  Before URL escaping, the Rails equivalent of the above URI looks like this:

```
https://domain.tld/resource?param[]=foo&param[]=bar&param[]=baz
```

I can manually wrangle `request.url` inside of my controller, but I'd rather not do this ad-hoc if I can help it.
Is there a standard way to support the first style of URI in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No standard way.

Any way I think it is not good idea to change it for whole rails application, because it breaks conventions (and probably some helpers).

Comment: Several frameworks use that to indicate a collection of parameters, e.g., an array or a list.

Comment: I agree with @DaveNewton here, as does the Wikipedia article. "While there is no definitive standard, most web frameworks allow multiple values to be associated with a single field." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Meh; AFAIC the important part of the answer is the "no standard way" part--I was just pointing out that the additional part isn't really correct. Not so wrong as to warrant downvotes IMO.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil I was a bit liberal with the downvote.  Unfortunately, you can't "un-downvote." :\  I could upvote to neutralize.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Good approach! :)  I like your edited answer much better.  FYI - my changes will be restricted to a specifically scoped group of controllers.